# Como valido por jquery que mi campo de mensaje no contenga un espacio?

Tags: jquery, regex

Quiero hacer la validación de mi textarea para que no escriban al principio ningun espacio en blanco

```
if( $("#comments").val() == ""  || $("#comments").attr("value").match(/^/s+$/)){
    $("#comments").focus().after("<span class='error'>This field is required.</span>");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con espacio en blanco (p.e. espacio, tabulador, salto de línea, todo lo anterior...)?¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Me refiero a que no ponga un tabulador al principio, salto de liniea ni esapcio en blanco, quiero que por lo menos ponga 5 caracteres pero que no sean espacios, hasta ahora he intentando que si el campo comentario es igual a /s, no hay mucha cosa en internet

Comment: Estás poniendo la barra al revés. Debería ser \ en lugar de /. Algo como esto: `/^\s+$/`

Comment: Gracias Solucionado

Comment: Para verificar que haya 5 caracteres que no sean espacios en blanco al principio: `/^\S{5}/` devuelve `false` si no lo cumple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás poniendo la barra al revés. En las expresiones regulares la barra \ delante de un carácter indica que ese carácter va a tener un significado especial en lugar de su significado literal (por ejemplo `\n` no significa el carácter `n` sino el de nueva línea).

Entonces, en tu expresión regular debería ser \ en lugar de /, y sería algo como esto `/^\s+$/`, con lo que el código quedaría así:

```
if( $("#comments").val() == ""  || $("#comments").attr("value").match(/^\s+$/)){
    $("#comments").focus().after("<span class='error'>This field is required.</span>");
    return false;
}
```